# My steering wheel rapidly jerks to left and I hear a knocking noise that's inconsistent when i let go of the gas but does it randomly when I'm driving

Tags: hyundai, steering

I have a 05 hyundai xg350 I bought from the dealer ship last yr. My problem started today when I was driving home. My steering wheel started pulling by itself when i let go of the gas i checked my tires and ball joints but those weren't it. It makes a knocking noise too but I have no idea what it is. Could it be my cv axle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please don't drive this car on public roads, if the "pulling by itself" means something else than the fact you didn't have your hands on the steering wheel. Have it towed. CV joints usually give some audible knocking warning when taking a turn, if they fail.